# kill a tid doesn't return an error

Tags: linux, pthreads, system-calls

Is there any way to detect that the PID is truly dead when a TID will respond to the kill system call and that will then act like the process is still alive.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/types.h>  // gettid()
#include <sys/syscall.h>

static int gettid()
{
  return syscall(SYS_gettid);
}

void *start(void *arg)
{
  printf("thread start is %d\n", gettid());
  (void)arg;
  while (1)
  {
    sleep(1);
  }
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t thread;

    printf("Process is %d\n", getpid());

    (void)pthread_create(&thread, nullptr, &start, nullptr);
    while (1)
    {
      sleep(1);
      // do_kill(thread);
    }
}
```

If you compile this

```
 g++ -std=c++11 starttid.cpp -lpthread
```

and the execute it the pid is one less than the tid. If you then kill the tid

```
kill -0 <tid>
```

The tid will respond and the error returned from kill will be 0. My problem is that I've got a program that runs a long time and doesn't have the option of being re-written. It tracks all the processes it ever launched. Since the process ID wraps around, a TID will sometimes replace the original PID. The program uses 'kill(0, PID)'' to check if the process is running. Since the TID will capture the kill this acts like the process is still alive even though it has long since exited.

Answer (score 0):

The old PID being reused for a new thread TID is not a different situation to that PID being reused for a new process PID.  Both are entirely possible if your process relies on polling with `kill(0, pid)` to see when processes exit - that method has an inherent race condition.

Your process should be using the `waitpid()` system call, perhaps paired with a `SIGCHLD` handler, to track the exiting of its child processes.